# Unpacking list of tuples

Tags: python

I was surprised today by the following code:

```py
testcases = [([1, 1, 1], 2, 2)]

for a, b, c in testcases:
    print(a, b, c)
```

it prints:

```
[1, 1, 1] 2 2
```

I expected an error and thought we'd need a second loop to get to tuples' elements. Could enyone explain to me how it works? I don't get how `a`, `b` and `c` are assigned. I used Python 3.6. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at what you have:

```
testcases = [([1, 1, 1], 2, 2)]
```

This is a list. Of size one. So `testcases[0]` is the only element there is.

So this code:

```
for a, b, c in testcases:
    pass
```

is a loop of length one. So each time through the loop (that is just the once), you get the element: `([1, 1, 1], 2, 2)` which is a `tuple`. Of size three.

So unpacking that: `a,b,c = testcases[0]` gives:

```
a == [1, 1, 1]
b == 2
c == 2
```

which is what you see printed.

Comment: I used a list of one element to simplify the question.
I don't get how the tuple is unpacked. I thought `a == ([1, 1, 1], 2, 2)` to happen and an error...

Comment: But usually when we give `x in y `, x is defined to something inside y but not to something inside of inside of y. how do we explain that?

Comment: But I think I see the point now. First an element of the list is taken and then the assignment happens. Since it's a tuple it works as you would expect and a,b,c are assigned. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

During the unpacking of tuple, the total number of variables on the left-hand side should be equivalent to the total number of values in given tuple.
Python gives the syntax to pass optional arguments (*arguments) for tuple unpacking of arbitrary length. All values will be assigned to every variable in the order of their specification and all remaining values will be assigned to *arguments .For example,

```
>>> tup = ("Elem1", "Elem2","Elem3","Elem4","Unpacking a tuple")
>>> (unp1,*unp2, unp3) = tup
>>> print(*unp2)
Elem2 Elem3 Elem4
>>> print(unp1)
Elem1
>>> print(unp3)
Unpacking a tuple
>>> print(type(unp1),type(unp3))
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
>>> print(type(unp2))
<class 'list'>
```

What’s happening at a lower level is that we’re creating a tuple of 5 elements and then looping over that tuple and taking each of the five items we get from looping and assigning them to three variables on the left hand side in order.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was just surprised as I didn't think about a sequence of things that happen on iteration:
1. First element of the list is taken
2. Assignment happens

If the assignment happened kind of straight away, only `a` would be assigned to the whole tuple. Hope you see my point/confusion.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope you now get a clear idea as to what's happening.